# how do I pass dir 'abc/file.js' as slug in django url?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have a url `url(r'^dev/(?P<file_name>[-\w]+)', dev_static)`,

in my view function `dev_view(request,file_name)`, I want to get `'abc/file.js'` as slug file_name.

how do i pass `'abc/file.js'` as the whole file_name? now the slug only get `'abc'`, it will cut everything after `'/'`

Comment: You regular expression doesn't allow `/` in the `file_name` pattern, because `/` is neither `-` nor a character matched by `\w`. Neither is `.`, for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `url` pattern like this:

```
url(r'^dev/(?P<file_name>[-\w/.]+)', dev_static)
```

That is, by adding `/` and `.` in the list of allowed characters, now it will match `abc/file.js`.